# C# Get font family when know font's name

Tags: c#, fonts, font-family, privatefontcollection

I have `PrivateFont` is declare like this

```
 PrivateFont = new PrivateFontCollection();
        string[] fontFiles = this.GetFontFiles();
        foreach (string fontFile in fontFiles)
        {
            PrivateFont.AddFontFile(fontFile);
        }
```

Then I get font info by index:

```
Font = new Font(PrivateFont.Families[2], 16);
```

Now, I want get font family by font name. How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way possible is (as I think your question)

```
var font = PrivateFont.Families
                     .Where(c => c.Name == "Arial")
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```